# Printer driver Lexmark X2350

Tags: print-drivers

I have just got an updated PC and want to connect my old printer to it but don't have a driver for it.

My new laptop is a HP running on windows 10 and my printer is a very old Lexmark X2350 (but works perfectly). I have tried the Lexmark website but my printer driver isn't on there ?

Where can I locate one please ?

Comment: Open Control Panel, Devices and Printers and select Add a Printer.  Make sure your printer is connected to the computer and then see if Windows 10 can add the Lexmark Printer. If not, try adding it as a Text Printer.

Comment: Hi thanks for responding , yes I have added the printer but when I  select the printer to print it says "driver unavailable"

Comment: You will probably have to replace the Lexmark Printer.

Comment: its my favourite printer :-(   12 years old but is prints perfectly ......

Comment: I found some drivers at https://www.lexmark.com/en_za/printer/2538/Lexmark-X2350 but the newest is for Windows Vista. It might work in Windows 10 but I can't say for sure... you probable want the "Windows Vista x64" one.

Answer (score 0):

> I have just got an updated PC and want to connect my old printer to it
> but don't have a driver for it.

[Lexmark Driver](http://support.lexmark.com/index?locale=EN&page=product&userlocale=EN_CA&productCode=LEXMARK_X2350#1)

I have checked a few Lexmark sites and there is not any driver for Windows 10.

For older printers, sometimes it works to use the Windows supplied driver. Control Panel, Devices and Printers and Add Printer.

Now since this did not work and then further the computer is new, so you will likely wish to upgrade it to Windows 11, then there is no way the printer is going to work in Windows 11.

So the best choice here (not necessarily what you desire) is to replace the printer with a new one that has drivers for Windows 10 and for Windows 11.

Good luck with this.

Comment: thanks for you help and investigation .... so i think i will revert back to my old laptop ans printer until i use the supply of ink cartridges and then move over to my new laptop and bluetooth printer when my old ink stock is depleted - thanks again for your help janet

Comment: That is a decent plan .  Longer term a new printer is in the cards.   (I have an HP 8610 that I got 5 years ago or so - Windows 7 and 8, it has proven to be good and to also work in Windows 11.